# Does $G$ have a normal abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, characters

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $|G|=2^\alpha n$ where $(2,n)=1$ and $\alpha$ is a positive integer.  Suppose that $\def\cd{\operatorname{cd}} n=\max \cd(G)$, and $n^2>\frac{1}{2}|G|$, where $\cd(G)$ is the set of all degrees of irreducible $\mathbb{C}$-characters.

> Question: Does $G$ have a normal abelian Sylow $2$-subgroup?

In the case $G''=1$, the answer is yes.  Since $n\in \cd(G)$, we know $F(G)= O_2(G)$. Then $|G:F(G)|\leqslant n$ and $\max \cd(F(G))\leqslant n/|G:F(G)|$ by [1, Lemma 12.25]. Hence, $|G:F(G)|=n$ and $F(G)=O_2(G)\in \operatorname{Syl}_2(G)$. Further, $F(G)$ is abelian.

In the case $G''\neq1$, we don't know the answer. We hope someone will give us some suggestions.

[1] *Isaacs, I. Martin*, Character theory of finite groups., New York, NY: Dover Publications, Inc. xii, 303 p. (1994). [ZBL0849.20004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0849.20004).

Comment: I think it follows from general results on solvable groups (by people such as Isaacs) that if a finite solvable group $G$ has an irreducible character $\chi$ of degree $[G:S]$ for $S \in {\rm Syl}_{2}(G),$ then $\chi$ is induced from a linear character of a Sylow $2$-subgroup. However, without further assumptions, the Sylow $2$-subgroup need not be Abelian and normal ( for example $G = S_{4}$ has an irreducible character of degree $3$). The additional assumption here that $\chi(1)^{2} > |G|/2$ forces $\chi$ to be faithful and also $G = O^{2}(G),$ but unfortunately it is not inductive.